# Arch Linux and optional dependencies

Tags: arch-linux, dynamic-linking

I installed XChat on an Arch Linux system. Every time I run it, I get the following error message:

```
Python interface loaded
Perl interface loaded
AutoLoad failed for: /usr/lib/xchat/plugins/tcl.so
libtcl8.5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So while the plugins for Python and Perl are loaded correctly, the Tcl plugin is not. In fact, `python2` and `perl` packages are installed on my system, while `tcl` package is not. Installing `tcl` fixes the problem.

Before installing `tcl`, I get:

```
ldd /usr/lib/xchat/plugins/tcl.so | grep tcl
    libtcl8.5.so => not found
```

After installing `tcl`, I get:

```
ldd /usr/lib/xchat/plugins/tcl.so | grep tcl
    libtcl8.5.so => /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so (0x00007fceba533000)
```

It seems that `tcl` is not a required dependency of `xchat`, but an optional one:

```
pacman -Qi xchat
...
Optional Deps  : enchant: for spell checking support
                 tcl: for tcl plugin
                 python2: for python plugin
...
```

Why is this the case? That is, why the `tcl` package is not installed along with `xchat` by default? Isn't `xchat` broken without `tcl`?

I filed a [bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/20168) more than two years ago, but I never really understood why things are this way in Arch Linux land. Please notice that while this bug is old, I'm only running this distribution on a daily basis since a couple of months, so I'm an Arch Linux newbie.

I could have asked on Arch Linux forums or mailing lists, but I'm quite interested in knowing the point of view of other Linux distributions users. Arch Linux users are also welcome, of course.

---

EDIT.

1. The error message I get when running XChat without `tcl` installed is clearly visible in the GUI, in the same place where messages are displayed.
2. My question can also be reworded in the following way: why XChat, despite having clearly been built with `--enable-tcl` or equivalent passed to the `configure` script, can be installed without a mandatory dependency on the `tcl` package? If one don't want `tcl`, he should use `--disable-tcl`.

---

EDIT. I opened a [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149480) on the Arch Linux forum, but I didn't get a satisfying answer. So I checked Debian and Gentoo, and it seems they don't have this problem.

Comment: Is it **really** broken though? Does that error prevent it from starting or is it just noise?

Comment: I forgot to say that despite that error message XChat is working great anyway. I don't think I need plugins at all.

Comment: So I don't understand your question at all. Clearly TCL isn't a required dependency.

Comment: I may be wrong, but software should be installed in such a way that the user should not be alarmed by error messages, even if they are relatively innocuous.

Comment: Isn't that message visible only when you launch xchat via the command line? Wouldn't most users run it from a menu/icon thing?

Comment: No, the message is clearly visible when I launch XChat GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's mostly a matter of complexity and how people choose to invest their time.

If you wanted an XChat binary package that doesn't show any warnings/errors related to missing libraries for plugins, you have essentially two choices:

- only include/configure "vital" plugins, and add hard dependencies for what those things require
- include each and every plugin available, and add hard dependencies for what those things require

The first option leaves you with an XChat package that doesn't have a lot of features at all. You'd then need an `xchat-perl` package, an `xchat-tcl` one, an `xchat-gtk`, ... All these packages need to be maintained, patched, upgraded, etc. That's a lot of work.

The second option gives you a bloated XChat package that pulls in lots of other stuff, most of which won't be used at all by the average user. Not really satisfactory for distributions like Arch.

You can try to find a sweet spot between these two, but chances are you won't find the perfect fit.

What the Arch devs apparently did with the package is ship a commonly used plugin without forcing the user to install the dependency. That (leaving out the error message for now) is actually pretty nice for the user: those who don't want/need the TCL don't have to install it to get XChat. Those who do can just install TCL and the XChat TCL plugin will just work.
So that's a nice compromise. If you, in the future, would like to use TCL to script your XChat, all you'll have to do is install TCL - you won't have to worry about updating XChat or installing yet another package.

As for the error message, it's purely cosmetic. Could it be fixed? Probably.
Could it be fixed easily in a way that still lets the plugin start working right after installing TCL (without additional packages or configuration changes, reverse dependency checks, ...): that's not all that certain.
Should the Arch devs/maintainers spend time on trying to remove this cosmetic issue? That's debatable. Giving that the software works, this should be pretty low priority.

Could *you* try and fix it one way or another? If it's important enough for you, probably. Give it a shot: find a better way of handling those plugins and dependencies, and file a bug or feature request, or get on the appropriate forum/mailing list for this type of thing.
Open source distros don't get better by magic. If you care enough about this, get involved.

Answer (score 3):

> why XChat, despite having clearly been built with --enable-tcl or
>   equivalent passed to the configure script, can be installed without a
>   mandatory dependency on the tcl package?

You are using Arch Linux. From the FAQ - [What makes Arch unique...](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FAQ#Q.29_What_makes_Arch_unique_amongst_other_.22minimal.22_distributions.3F):

> Arch packaging is designed to be minimal, and ***optional*** package
>   dependencies ***are never automatically installed***. Rather, the user is
>   simply notified of their existence during package installation,
>   resulting in a slimmer system.

[XChat](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xchat/) package details:

> dbus-glib
>   gtk2
>   hicolor-icon-theme
>   libnotify
>   openssl
>   enchant (optional) - for spell checking support
>   python2 (optional) - for python plugin
>   *tcl (**optional**) - for tcl plugin*

EDIT: In reply to your comment below:

I'm not sure I get your meaning there... Optional dependencies are only used for certain features/functionalities of an application. Those dependencies are NOT needed if the said features aren't used. Optional dependencies are usually used when, for various reasons, it's not really possible to split a package into sub-modules (a sub-module would have only non-optional dependencies since you'd need all of them in order to use that sub-module's functionality). An example of package + sub-modules is [exaile](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?O=0&K=exaile).

Now, about that particular error/warning message that you were getting there... I think Mat pretty much summed it up in his post and I really have nothing more to add.

Comment: But I wonder why missing packages that lead to "not found" entries are considered optional.